# CSV file data replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have many .csv files which looks like

```
header01,header02,header03,
data01,data02,data03,
data11,data12,data13,
data21,data22,data23,
data31,data32,data33,
```

I need an short function with that I can overwrite the [1] cell in the data section from data02 to something like test_data02.
I need to replace a big amount of cells in csv-files with that method, maybe I can read the line line in the file and save it as new one, so I knew it's definitely done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas library to work with csv's it's much simple.

So you open your csv :

```
df = pandas.read_csv('your_file.csv')
```

Get your cell value with :

```
value = df.iloc[i]['header02']
```

Where `i` is your row number

Then you can change any cell with this command :

```
df.set_value(i, 'header02', 'test_' + value)
```

Your first parameter is the row number, second is column name and third is the replacement value

Answer (score 0):

```
data =[]
path = 'test.csv'

with open (path,'r') as csvfiler:
    for i, line in enumerate(csvfiler):
        if i != 0:
            i-=1
            line = line.split('\n')[0].split(',')
            line[1]="test_data"+str(i)+"2"
            line=','.join(line)
            line+="\n"
        data.append(line)

with open (path,'w') as csvfilew:
    for line in data:
        csvfilew.write(line)
```